# Cursor on Spinner - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, spinner

In my view I have some objects (textview, edittext and some spinners).

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner"/>
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_edittext1"/>
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_edittext2"/>
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_spinner2"/>
```

When I open the view, the cursor automatically goes on the first `edittext`. And then, when I'm on the second `edittext` the cursor doent's go on the second `spinner`. All I want is the cursor goes on the first `spinner`, then on the `edittexts` and at the end on the second `spinner`